# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip (PHP) not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am trying to use the Twitter Bootstrap Popover / Tooltip but I am getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'popover'
```

I have the following in my functions file to include the files, which can be seen in the source and direct to the correct scripts when clicked:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dcr_enqueue_scripts');

if(!function_exists('dcr_enqueue_scripts')):
function dcr_enqueue_scripts(){

    wp_register_script('tooltip',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bs-tooltip.js','jquery');
    wp_register_script('popover',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bs-popover.js',array('jquery','tooltip'),'1.0');
    wp_enqueue_script('tooltip');
    wp_enqueue_script('popover');

}
endif;
```

With the following element expecting the popover:

```
<th><span>Description:</span><img class="popoverthis" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/info.png" data-content="This is the content" title="Title"></th>
```

And the jQuery included on the page to call the popover function is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.popoverthis').popover({
        placement: "bottom"
    });
});
```

Any ideas on resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a demo of your site and point to where the problem area is to take a look? Your setup should work. Are you including the necessary CSS for the tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check for:

- order of pages loading - is your popover  being execute before jquery or `jquery.popover.js` plugin is being called?

If this is issue, you'll have to bump/lower priority of your enque script as in:

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dcr_enqueue_scripts', **5**); // default is 10`

- do you have correct version of jQuery (wordpress bundles one and it sometimes can be older than is required for external scripts)?
- Open firebug/web inspector and manually run:
  `jQuery('.popoverthis').popover({    placement: "bottom"    });`

To see what goes wrong

**Update**: there are few more things that can go wrong (and this is list how to fix your problem):

- You are including two **jQuery's** on the site (probably by another plugin) - 1.4.2 comes after 1.7.2 and breaks basic bootstrap javascripts.
- You're missing **Bootstrap CSS** info that is required by this plugin. It actually works, but it displays the tooltip info in the bottom of the site since **CSS** is not there to make it look pretty.

**Solution**: use a standalone popovover plugin like this one by crowdfavorite:
 https://github.com/crowdfavorite/jquery-popover and also include its **CSS** files.

(you could also pull in bootstrap's **CSS** but it will probably break your sites **CSS**)

Comment: Thanks for the response, the scripts are loaded in the correct order as can be seen in the source of the page.

The version of jQuery used is 1.7.2 which is the latest version.

When I run the code manually I get the same error:
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'popover'

I have tried a number of different tooltip plugins and all have given the same results of Object has no method...

Comment: Any chance you can give me the url?

Comment: I have now added the word "Testing" down the bottom of the homepage here: http://www.discoversolar.co.uk/

You will see the error in the console.

Comment: Two things: 
- bootstrap plugins wrap window.jQuery that doesnt't exist in your userspace. Try chaging it to (jQuery)
- you're using jquery 1.4.2 which might be too old for boostrap (Heads up! All javascript plugins require the latest version of jQuery.)

Comment: I've updated post to explain the core of your problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any call to $.noConflict();

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

I tried jQuery('.popoverthis').hide() from the console with the same result, just before the site went down.

Comment: The site is not down, just a bit intermittently slow! I have never used noConflict before, do I call this in the external js files or from the call on the page?

Comment: look at the example in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ it's well explained.

Comment: I have tried adding this into the code but the same error is still shown. I think I did it right!

Comment: @ElliotReeve You did it right. and .hide() is working. I'm just wondering if you can popover on a class instead of an id.

Comment: I have used the same tool tip on another site using a class and not had any problems.

Comment: @ElliotReeve I'm pretty sure it's a javascript conflict. Can you try to hide the other .js. You may find where the conflict come from.